# Security of a single sign-on token in weird Flash game architecture

Tags: php, flash, security, single-sign-on, actionscript-2

Here is a security question regarding single-use sign-on tokens:

I have an old-school Actionscript 2 Flash game.  It is presented via a PHP script, but sometimes it is presented in isolation of an HTML/JS/PHP framework in cases where other sites embed the game by pointing to the SWF file directly.  The Flash movie has a way for users to log in with a username/password or via Facebook.  Once logged in, I want to give the user access to external features related to the game, which exist on standard HTML/JS/PHP pages, and which should be automatically authenticated for that user.  These features exist on the same server that the Flash movie communicates with and which handles the logins.  Since I would be opening these pages from a potentially "isolated" SWF file, where I may not have any session data that could facilitate authentication, I need another way to do this.  I could simply ask the user to log in again on these external pages, but that could prove to be cumbersome, and I don't want to worry about protecting multiple points of entry against brute force login attempts, for example.

The one common piece here is the database.  The game communicates over a socket connection to the server which uses the database which is also available to these external pages.

My thought was that any time a user needs to access an external page, I would generate a UUID (4), save it to the database and associate it with that user, and then send them to a URL that passes that UUID as a parameter.  When the external page loads, it immediately deletes that UUID reference from the database, and in its place, creates a new cookie-based session (using data unrelated to the UUID) associated with the intended user account, logging them in transparently.

Is this secure?  It would be possible to see this UUID traveling over the wire as part of the HTTP request, but when it is processed, it will only allow it to be honored the first time the server sees it.  I suspect there is something wrong with this approach, however.  If I am able to provide the UUID as a POST variable, and call my external pages under HTTPS, would this then be secure?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I can't see how your approach would allow you to get a user his account data (assuming you have it), when one launches you app through different entry points...

Comment: When the user requests, or is sent to, an external authenticated page by the server, at that time the server would generate and store a UUID in the database, associated with that user.  On the other side of the request, when the client browser is loading a page that has that UUID as part of its request, the database can retrieve the intended user account.  In the case where the game is loaded "in isolation", it is still communicating with a back end that I control, and which can authenticate users and write to the database.